# How to intercept hibernate query by column type

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-integration, hibernate-mapping, interceptor

I am trying to intercept Hibernate query execution, Here is my hibernate mapping

```
<class name="com.model.Parent" table="Parent"
        optimistic-lock="version" dynamic-update="true" dynamic-insert="true"
        lazy="true" >
<property name="id"
            type="org.hibernate.usertype.UserType" column="OBJECT_ID" />
 ( Here UserType is GUID format).....
```

If the generated query like the following

```
select * from Parent p_ where p_.id = ? OR p_.id in (?,?,?)
```

need to replace `?` with `HEXTORAW(?)`  for tables (columns defined with RAW).
Required query should be like this

```
select * from Parent p_ where p_.id = HEXTORAW(?) OR p_.id in (HEXTORAW(?),HEXTORAW(?),HEXTORAW(?))
```

Since I am working with existing system, can't change database column types.

How to find columns defined by RAW on the query execution (if i use interceptors or any other filters)?
and how to apply **HEXTORAW()** on those found columns?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Interceptor.onPrepareStatement](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html#onPrepareStatement(java.lang.String)) and Register it the `SessionFactory`

But you would have to make sure that the interceptor modifies only the required field parameters to HEXTORAW() not all.